# How to Avoid repeated route for same page access from different Component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

i have assigned these routers to the App.js file

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login/>} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} exact />
      <Route path="/dashboard/:userId/home" element={<Home/>} exact />
      <Route path="/dashboard/:userId/userprofile/:userId/home" element={<Home/>} exact />
      <Route path="/dashboard/:userId" element={<Dashboard/>} />
      <Route path="/userprofile/:userId" element={<UserProfile/>} />
      <Route path="/dashboard/:userId/userprofile/:userId" element={<UserProfile/>} />
      <Route path="/:userId" element={<PageNotFound/>} />
    </Routes>
```

well i have some repeated router path like :
<Route path="/dashboard/:userId/home" element={} exact />
<Route path="/dashboard/:userId/userprofile/:userId/home" element={} exact />
both the route display same page :

but now when i go to dashboard from home that was displayed from the dashboard itself :

its shows me error

`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/:userI/home/dashboard/:userId`

i dont want to add any further repeated path component in my router in app.js

how to fix this !

Comment: Which version of react router are you using? From your example, it apparent that you are using v6 (element attribute instead of component). Does v6 support exact?

Answer (score 0):

So after searching and asking from different servers , i am upto an answer and that is to use `useHistory` from `react-router-dom` as i don't wanted the previous routes to be there on the url ...

Its make code clean and logical , and  i recommend using both `Link` &
`UseHistory` as we can have diiferent use cases

Comment: Answer needs more explaination and ideally accompany a snippet or code. How would useHistory ensure that there wouldn't be previous routes in the url???